# Loop through array within array from qraphql

Tags: php, laravel, graphql

I have below array data

```
array:1 [▼
"data" => array:1 [▼
 "collections" => array:1 [▼
  "edges" => array:58 [▼
    0 => array:1 [▼
      "node" => array:3 [▼
        "id" => "1"
        "title" => "Company"
        "image" => array:1 [▼
          "src" => "myimage.png"
        ]
      ]
    ]
    1 => array:1 [▼
      "node" => array:3 [▼
        "id" => "2"
        "title" => "Popcorn"
        "image" => array:1 [▼
          "src" => "myimage.png"
        ]
      ]
    ]
  ]
]
```

When I try to loop using below code

```
@foreach ($shopify as $item)
  @foreach ($item['collections'] as $key => $data)
    <pre>
       @php
         print_r($data);exit();
       @endphp
    </pre>
  @endforeach
@endforeach
```

I got below data

```
Array
(
[0] => Array
    (
        [node] => Array
            (
                [id] => 1
                [title] => Company
                [image] => Array
                   (
                        [src] => 'myimage.png'
                   )
            )

    )

[1] => Array
    (
        [node] => Array
            (
                [id] => 2
                [title] => Popcorn
                [image] => Array
                    (
                        [src] => 'myimage.png'
                    )

            )

    )
```

My problem is I cannot get the `id`, `title` etc inside the array. When I try to loop it gives `undefined index` problem?

Any Idea how to get the `id`, `title` as well as `image(src)`

I got collection data from shopify using graphql api, and try to integrate in laravel

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Loop through array within array from qraphql using laravel](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/64320503/loop-through-array-within-array-from-qraphql-using-laravel)

Comment: Oh my mistake, because of net lagging it post two times.. I deleted the others

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I suppose you can simplify your code to this:

```
@foreach ($shopify['data']['collections']['edges'] as $edge)
    {{ $edge['node']['id'] }} - {{ $edge['node']['title'] }}
    <img src="{{ $edge['node']['image']['src'] }}">
@endforeach
```

Comment: yeah it's working. Before that I try like this but I forgot `['edges']` thanks

Comment: Delete your second question, it's a duplicate of this one.

Comment: what my second question? I didn't get